# Detect iframe src change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Lets say an `<iframe>` is initially loaded pointing to a certain src. The user clicks on a hyperlink and the contents of the iframe changes.

I would like to detect that new src of the iframe in full.

Unfortunately it appears to only provide the original src when a change is detected. It detects the change, just not what it changed to.

Perhaps it is a browser-specific issue. I am using chrome.

```
$(function(){
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        var src = $("iframe").attr('src')
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vud8S/7/

Comment: You cannot due to same origin policy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fortunately it is not possible to get an URL of an iframe from a different domain** than it's parent page. You will not be able to read the full url.

If you try to read the documents location (of an iframe whose src is a differnt domain) than you will get a permission error that looks similar to this: "Error: Permission denied to get property Location.href"

This is due to **"Same Origin Policy"**. More details on that: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy

Comment: Oh I see, yes I heard about the same origin policy. Sigh that kind of sucks for those not abusing it but hey, that's life I guess.